# Component dissapears upon entry into text input field (React)

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and I am trying to create a multi-step form. The problem i'm running into is that when I try to type into the text field, my entire component dissapears from the page. I can see that the value is changing though but I dont get why my component dissapears. Here is my code:

Code for the handle change function and state in parent component

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
        step: 0,
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        email: '',
        phoneNumber: '',
        address: '',
        personalWebsite: '',
    })

//handles a change in input field
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.name)
        setState ({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
    };
```

code for the input field in child component

```
<div>
     <label htmlFor="firstName" className='block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900'>First Name</label>
      <input type="text" name='firstName' className='bg-purple-200 border border-purple-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-purple-500 focus:border-purple-500 block w-full p-2.5' onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)} value={state.firstName}/>
</div>
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: check the console and see if there are any errors, might show you what's wrong. Attach it to your question if there's any.

Comment: Another thing is that you need to spread the rest of the state because you are going to lose it, `setState({...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })`